# Getting nodes from an ArrayList

Tags: java

In a simple array, you can do something like this (not my own code, taken from http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~sriram/21/spring07/code/heap.java)

```
Node top = myArray[index];
```

This assigns the value of Node to the element at the specific index in the array.

But doing:

```
Node top = myArrayList.get(index);
```

probably won't work since we are only getting its value, not the whole Node...

How would one do the same thing in an ArrayList?

Comment: @MattBall Well for the array, it's ints, and for the ArrayList it's <E>, will be using Integer type though.

Comment: @B.A. ArrayList internally maintains array. So when you do myArrayList(index) its basically fetching you the same an element at that index(ie myArray[index]). It might return you a type Object if which needs to be downcasted if you are not using generics.

Comment: You really need to show declarations for `myArray` and `myArrayList`. The top code won't work if you have `int myArray[]`, and the bottom code will work fine with `List<Node> myArrayList`.

Comment: @chrylis Upon second look, the code defines an inner class Node, so it's applicable for the class only and not Node in general I guess. I have decided not to use Node for my ArrayList method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong, the second sentence is correct.

Comment: The value you get from the ArrayList it is just what you put... so if you do arraylist.add(nodeinstance); to an empty ArrayList, when you later do arraylist.get(0) you would the exact/complete instance

Comment: But it would return me the value, not the instance right?

Comment: It will return the instance... but just checking... what do you consider a value?

Comment: You're probably right... If it contains Integer type it would return Integer objects right?

Comment: That is correct, if you add Integer, you get Integer; if you add Node then you get Node, and so on...